# How to remove back button after a button click

Tags: angular, ionic2

I need to hide back button after a function is been executed, like i need to hide if a button is been clicked

```
<ion-navbar  hideBackbutton="hide" >
        <ion-title>Milk Report</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
<button (click)="hideBackButton()"> button </button>
```

in my .ts file

```
export class MilkPage {
    hide: boolean = false;}
hideBackButton(){
        this.hide = true;
    }
```

This is not working for me could someone share me right method to hide back button

Comment: Is this for Angular 1 or Angular 2+?

Comment: you want to hide back button or ion-navbar? if back button then where on sub page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these should work:

```
<ion-navbar [hideBackButton]="hide">

<ion-navbar hideBackButton="{{ hide }}">
```

But if for some reason the `ion-navbar` component still doesn't see the change (maybe the `hideBackButton` attribute simply needs to be present to work), you may have to just do something like this:

```
<ion-navbar *ngIf="hide" hideBackButton>
    <ion-title>Milk Report</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-navbar *ngIf="!hide">
    <ion-title>Milk Report</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

Comment: Your second suggestion did the trick for me, although it definetely is a workaraound for the problem. I tried binding the hideBackButton property to a typescript variable without success. It seems to me that the binding happens prior to my logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button ng-click="hideBackButton();showBtn=false;" ng-show="showBtn"> button </button>
```

Comment: In angular js way this is html and js

Comment: You have posted question with `javascript` tag